# Auto rotation, proximity sensor issues in Xperia Arc S after updating to ICS

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sony-xperia-arc, sensors, auto-rotation

My auto-rotation and sensors was working fine in my Xperia Arc S with Gingerbread, but when I updated it to Ice Cream Sandwich via Sony PC Companion, now the auto-rotation and some sensors are not working. I have also checked it by reflashing the other custom ROM, but same problem exists there. I guess its a Sony's built-in bugs, because I have also checked other Xperia Arc S with ICS, same issues exists there. Any help in this regards will be highly appreciated! Please help me how to fix it, or any other alternate to auto-rotation and how to turn off proximity sensor manually.

Comment: What "other" custom ROM did you use? Is the device rooted? You say "other sensors" but really only talk about the proximity sensor; what else is affected?

Comment: Al Everett Thanks for your reply, Other custom ROM that I used:ultimate HD (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1920207), other sensors means: compass sensor, light sensor, proximity sensor. Can you help me ? I shall be very thanksfull to you :)

Comment: Yes my device is rooted, but problem was there before rooted. Can you help me that which files to change to fixed this problem as I am also an android application developer but dont know much about this problem.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going to be of little help. I'm not into flashing custom ROMs. However, there are other people here who are, and they may be able to help you. One other thing: comments are, by their nature, impermanent. It would be a good idea to edit your question to include the important information you clarified in your latest comments.

Comment: yes, thanks for your advice, actually i am new here. if I go back to the official ICS (unrooted), then can you help me on stock ROM?